# How to start another tour from the current tour in shepherd js?

Tags: javascript

Library- https://shepherdjs.dev/docs/index.html

I have created 2 tours in `shepherdjs`. One for moving to a specific page and another to add a product using a modal.

How can I start the second tour once the user clicks `Next` on a specific step of the previous tour.

I added the `js` tag to this question because the `shepherdjs` tag is not available.

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Edited question to be more descriptive.

Comment: Complete the first tour when moving to this specific page, and then another when this target page renders.

Answer (score 1):

When you setup the tour you can tell what to do when the next button clicked of each steps:

```
    tour.addStep({
  id: 'example-step',
  text: 'This step is attached to the bottom of the <code>.example-css-selector</code> element.',
  attachTo: {
    element: '.example-css-selector',
    on: 'bottom'
  },
  classes: 'example-step-extra-class',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Next',
      action: tour.next
    }
  ]
});
```

For the action of next instead adding "tour.next" you can add your own function like "StartTheNextTour"
In that function you can exit from the first tour and start the 2nd one. You can do this in any steps you whish.